# how to reuse one common submodule in different projects?

Tags: android, gradle, git-submodules

I have an android project, but now I need to develop several projects for other companies ,but these projects are almost the same, only some colors、 icons and activities are needed to be customized, so I put the origin codes and resources into a submodule, and each project add the submodule, and put replace  resources in the main module, but how can I replace an Activity that declared in the submodule? I tried to add a same Activity with the same package in the main module, but build failed because of duplicated classes.

Comment: `only some colors、 icons and activities are needed to be customized` is it just changing the graphics or also at code level?

Comment: @Sagar yes, for example:one need to show a Toast, but others not

Comment: are you still looking for answer?